# Specify a PostgreSQL field name with a dash in its name in ogr2ogr

Tags: gdal, postgresql, ogr2ogr

Using ogr2ogr to import a GeoPackage to a PostGIS database, I want to cast a field to another type, using -lco  COLUMN_TYPES=

The field name, however has a dash in it's name. I tried:

> -lco  COLUMN_TYPES="\"plus-type\"=text"

> -lco  COLUMN_TYPES="\\"plus-type\\"=text"

> -lco  COLUMN_TYPES="plus-type=text"

So how do I specify the a fieldname which in PostreSQL should be double quoted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a try and I did not need to do anything special, despite to disable the name laundering that by default changes the dash character into underscore. See https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/pg.html

> **LAUNDER=[YES/NO]**: Defaults to YES. This may be "YES" to force new fields created on this layer to have their field names "laundered"
> into a form more compatible with PostgreSQL. This converts to lower
> case and converts some special characters like "-" and "#" to "_". If
> "NO" exact names are preserved. If enabled the table (layer) name will
> also be laundered.

I run ogr2ogr with these parameters

```
-lco column_types=plus-type=text -lco launder=no
```

The column "plus-type" was integer in the source data and ogrinfo shows now about the new PostGIS table that the column type is changed into text.

```
FID Column = ogc_fid
Geometry Column = wkb_geometry
plus-type: String (0.0)
OGRFeature(lcotest):1
  plus-type (String) = 3
  POINT (309 269)
```

Comment: thanks. I should have mentioned that I allready had -lco launder=no in my parameters. That said, your solution works! So it must have been the double quotes.

Comment: This works also for me `-lco column_types="plus-type"=text -lco launder=no`.